# Angular Material 2 : mat-button css to look like mat-button-toggle

Tags: html, css, angular, sass, angular-material2

I need help in css to obtain a [Button](https://material.angular.io/components/button/examples)

```
<button mat-icon-button>
    <mat-icon>format_align_left</mat-icon>
</button>
```

Equivalent (in design) to a [Button toggle](https://material.angular.io/components/button-toggle/examples)

```
<mat-button-toggle-group>
  <mat-button-toggle>
    <mat-icon>format_align_left</mat-icon>
  </mat-button-toggle>
</mat-button-toggle-group>
```

Because in a real toolbar (see button toggle for example), some of the command (eg : indent) are not toggled but just clicked.

But i don't find the exact css to apply on my button...

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use any of the built-in angular styles directly, such as `mat-button-toggle-checked` which applies the toggle button's filled background color.

A toggle button that is not "on" or pressed is basically a raised button without a minimum width. So, to make a regular button look like a toggle button:

```
<button mat-button mat-raised-button style="min-width: unset;">
    <mat-icon>format_align_left</mat-icon>
</button>
```

A toggle button that **is** "on" or pressed is basically a raised button without a minimum width filled with the "on" color from the toggle button. So, to make a regular button look like a toggle button that is "on":

```
<button mat-button mat-raised-button style="min-width: unset;"
    class="mat-button-toggle-checked">
    <mat-icon>format_align_left</mat-icon>
</button>
```

You can combine the two in one button to produce your own "standalone" toggle button using ngClass and some simple logic:

```
<button mat-button mat-raised-button style="min-width: unset;"
    [ngClass]="{'mat-button-toggle-checked' : on}"
    (click)="on = !on;">
    <mat-icon>format_align_left</mat-icon>
</button>
```

But of course you don't need to do that because you can use a single `mat-button-toggle` inside a `mat-button-toggle-group` with the `multiple` option to have a standalone toggle button:

```
<mat-button-toggle-group multiple>
    <mat-button-toggle value="left">
        <mat-icon>format_align_left</mat-icon>
    </mat-button-toggle>
</mat-button-toggle-group>
```

Comment: Thank you ! I couldn't find the style by myself... It's more like that :   <button mat-button style="min-width: unset;">
        <mat-icon>favorite</mat-icon>
</button>

Comment: Okay - but `<button mat-button style="min-width: unset;"><mat-icon>favorite</mat-icon></button>` does not look like a toggle button - which is what you asked for. If you want an icon-only button, use `<button mat-button mat-icon-button><mat-icon>favorite</mat-icon></button>`

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/toggle-stack without "mat-raised-button" it's look like more to a toggle button (for me).

Comment: That's because you put it in a button toggle group - you didn't show that in your question. If you try to use it outside a group, it doesn't look like a toggle button unless you use raised button.

Comment: Agreed sorry, all examples i have seen was in a group.